# how to use calculate height and width using MediaQuery?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, iso

Suppose I have a container with height 60. How this 60 can be written in mediaquery?

example code:

```
Container(height:60,)
```

I want this container looks like having 60 as height but in responsive way.

Comment: How to calculate height and width using MediaQuery ? Sorry for that grammar mistake.

Comment: Please stop using MediaQuery.  Prefer LayoutBuilder.  And don't do sizing based on screen realestate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try this:

```
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

Container(height:size.height * 60/580,);
```

here `60` is the height you prefer and `580` is the height of your device in ui design.

Comment: if i use the size variable instant of 580 then it will work for all screens right ?

Comment: no, you are understand it wrong. imagine you have a design and telling you put a box with height of 60 in your screen and also that design is a iphone 6. for example iphone 6 height is 580 pix. so if you want to design a box that has a responsive depend of that design, should get the height of target device which is  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and Multiply it to 60/580 which is the aspect ratio of that box's height to design device's height.

Comment: then what about height: size. height * 60 / size. height  that will work for all devices ?

Comment: no. Because this is no different with height: 60 and its not responsive, just static value.

Answer (score 0):

this will help  `var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`;

and also some plugins there which can help
[Pubdev Plugins](https://pub.dev/packages?q=responsive)

Answer (score 0):

```
Size size = MediaQuert.of(context).size

Container(
   //width: size.width * 0.1 //10% width of Device
   height: size.height * 0.1 //10% height of Device
),
```